# Django - Scheduled event

Tags: django, events, schedule

I would like the `status` of this model change when the current date exceeds the `expiration_date`. I was reading about background tasks and Asynchronous Tasks with Celery ... Am I going the right way? Is there a more direct way of doing this? If anyone can give me a tip or something to follow I would be grateful. Thanks for listening.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status          = models.BooleanField...
    expiration_date = models.DateField....
    [...]
```

Comment: I don't think you need a scheduled task here. You can just calculate if the item is expired based on the `expiration_date` field.

Comment: Can I make this change automatically without a post method or something that forces it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store the `status` in the model, you can simply [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) it, so if the model looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    expiration_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

so *without* a `status` field. Then you can make an annotation with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    satus=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(expiration_date__gt=Now()),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

The `MyModel` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.status` that is `True` if the `expiration_date` is in the future.

If you need this often, you can make a [*manager* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) that automatically annotates the items each time you access `MyModel.objects`:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            satus=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(expiration_date__gt=Now()),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    expiration_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

This does not require scheduled tasks, which are hard to manage: what if you later edit the `expiration_date`, then you need to somehow "remove" the task already scheduled and schedule a new one, which can be "tricky". If the scheduled task is already completed you then have to "undo" it.

By using annotations, you make sure that `status` is simply based on the value of `expiration_date` compared to `Now()`.